# resize a PNG on the fly in android

Tags: java, android

So I have an image view

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bookImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/gallery_thumb"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="70dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="329dp" />
```

I need to display this image:

[image]

Which is a PNG, however the image is larger than my image view, so the image view stretches.

How can i force the image to stay inside the imageView so that it doesnt stretch?

This how I currently load the image:

```
ImageView bookImage = findViewById(R.id.bookImage);
bookImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.bookcovernot);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define image scale type with the following:

```
bookImage.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
bookImage.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
```

or in your layout

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bookImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/gallery_thumb"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="70dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="329dp" />
```

Check [ScaleType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) doc for more info.

Answer (score 0):

you can even try this in your layout xml

```
     <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            .../>
```